# Isomorphism in homology

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-cohomology

$\require{AMScd}$Let $G, H, K$ be groups and suppose that we have a diagram
$$\begin{CD}
G @>f_1>> H\\
@Vg_1VV\\
K
\end{CD}
$$
where morphisms $f_1$ and $g_1$ induce isomorphism in homology. Can one builds a group $U$ with the properties

1. The following square commutes:
   $$\begin{CD}
   G @>f_1>> H\\
   @Vg_1VV @VVg_2V\\
   K @>>f_2> U
   \end{CD}
   $$

   $g_2$ and $f_2$ induce isomorphism in homology.

I tried to prove that $U:=K*_G H$ will be such a group. I used Mayer-Vietoris sequence, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Now asked on MathOverflow: [Isomorphism in homology](https://mathoverflow.net/q/301883)